# SQL query (of minute time series data points) to get all data points within a given hour plus the first data point of the following hour?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a table of data values keyed by a stream id and a time stamp, basically each row represents a minute of data given a specific stream at a specific minute, and the table has many streams and many minutes.

So I'm trying to query over a set of streams, any data points within a given hour plus the (chronologically) first data point of the following hour (this is the part I'm having trouble with).

It's also difficult because any of the 60+1 minute rows could be missing, and I want the single data point even if is in the middle of the hour, as long as its the first one.  So I can't just query over '2019-12-06 00:00:00' - '2019-12-06 01:01:00'.

Sorry this is probably unclear but if you look at my examples, I think it will make sense.

I made a couple attempts that work on my test cases but I have a feeling like they are not universal or I could be doing it a better way.

```
SELECT stream_id, time_stamp, my_data
FROM data_points_minutes
WHERE
  time_stamp >= '2019-12-06 00:00:00'
  AND time_stamp < '2019-12-06 01:00:00'
  AND stream_id IN (123, 456, 789)
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT ON (stream_id) stream_id, time_stamp, my_data
FROM data_point_minutes
WHERE
  time_slot >= '2019-12-06 01:00:00'
  AND time_slot < '2019-12-06 02:00:00'
  AND stream_id IN (123, 456, 789)
ORDER BY
  stream_id, time_stamp;
```

This works for my test data but I'm worried that the SELECT DISTINCT only working because they are already sorted by timestamp but would not work if they weren't, which led me to

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT stream_id, time_stamp, my_value
    FROM
      data_point_minutes
    WHERE
      time_stamp >= '2019-12-06 00:00:00'
      AND time_stamp < '2019-12-06 01:00:00'
      AND stream_id IN (123, 456, 789)
  ) as q1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT
      DISTINCT ON (stream_id) stream_id, time_stamp, my_value
    FROM
      data_point_minutes
    WHERE
      time_stamp >= '2019-12-06 01:00:00'
      AND time_stamp < '2019-12-06 02:00:00'
      AND stream_id IN (123, 456, 789)
    ORDER BY
      stream_id, time_stamp ASC
  ) AS q2
ORDER BY
  stream_id, time_stamp;
```

and I think this is mostly working, and I might go with this but nesting this way seems a little awkward to me so I'm hoping someone could suggest something more elegant.

Comment: The use of the `distinct on` syntax indicates that you seem to be using postgres. If so, please remove the mysql tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could `or` the condition on the upper bound of the date range with an equality check on the next timestamp, that can be computed with a subquery:

```
select stream_id, time_stamp, my_data
from data_points_minutes
where
    stream_id in (123, 456, 789)
    and time_stamp >= '2019-12-06 00:00:00' 
    and (
        time_stamp < '2019-12-06 01:00:00'
        or time_stamp = (
            select min(d1.time_stamp) 
            from data_points_minutes d1
            where d1.stream_id in (123, 456, 789) and d1.timestamp >= '2019-12-06 01:00:00'
        )
    )
```

Or possibly, if you want the next data point for each `stream_id`, you can *correlate* the subquery:

```
select stream_id, time_stamp, my_data
from data_points_minutes d
where
    stream_id in (123, 456, 789)
    and time_stamp >= '2019-12-06 00:00:00' 
    and (
        time_stamp < '2019-12-06 01:00:00'
        or time_stamp = (
            select min(d1.time_stamp) 
            from data_points_minutes d1
            where d1.stream_id = d.stream_id and d1.timestamp >= '2019-12-06 01:00:00'
        )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I think the issue with this is it would include one row for the minimum timestamp over all streams, but I want to get a minimum timestamp for each stream.  -- edit sorry didn't see your edits let me test this.

Comment: @nodsknowingly: yes I suspected that, I updated my answer shortly before you posted that comment.

Comment: yeah I think its the same issue, I think it makes sense because the subquery uses min so it only returns one minimum for all the streams.  

I like the idea of using the or with equality though, it's much better than doing a union.  I'm going to try and figure something out using that.

Answer (score 0):

What you basically want is the minimum value of timestamp for each stream in the given row set (selection from the next hour) and argmin, the row on which minimum value is achieved. There are a few ways to solve it, but probably the most readable way is using [window functions](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/).

Here is a query which generates some test values:

```
WITH Data AS (
  select * from (values 
    (NOW()                , 1), 
    (NOW() + interval '1m', 1),   
    (NOW() + interval '1m', 2), 
    (NOW() + interval '2m', 2)
  ) T(ts, stream)
)
SELECT * FROM Data;

              ts               | stream 
-------------------------------+--------
 2019-12-14 01:08:07.556573+00 |      1
 2019-12-14 01:09:07.556573+00 |      1
 2019-12-14 01:09:07.556573+00 |      2
 2019-12-14 01:10:07.556573+00 |      2
```

A query which calculates the minimum timestamps and its argmin for each stream:

```
WITH Data AS (
  select * from (values 
    (NOW()                , 1), 
    (NOW() + interval '1m', 1),   
    (NOW() + interval '1m', 2), 
    (NOW() + interval '2m', 2)
  ) T(ts, stream)
),
RankedData AS (
  SELECT ts, 
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY stream ORDER BY ts), 
         stream 
  FROM Data
)        
SELECT * FROM RankedData WHERE rank=1;

              ts               | rank | stream 
-------------------------------+------+--------
 2019-12-14 01:12:08.676228+00 |    1 |      1
 2019-12-14 01:13:08.676228+00 |    1 |      2
```

If you build `Data` as selection of rows from the next hour, it will solve your problem:

```
SELECT stream_id, time_stamp, my_data
FROM data_points_minutes
WHERE
  time_stamp >= '2019-12-06 00:00:00'
  AND time_stamp < '2019-12-06 01:00:00'
  AND stream_id IN (123, 456, 789)
UNION (
WITH Data AS (
SELECT stream_id, time_stamp, my_data
FROM data_point_minutes
WHERE
  time_slot >= '2019-12-06 01:00:00'
  AND time_slot < '2019-12-06 02:00:00'
  AND stream_id IN (123, 456, 789)
),
RankedData AS (
  SELECT time_stamp, my_data 
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY stream_id ORDER BY time_stamp), 
         stream_id
  FROM Data
)
SELECT stream_id, time_stamp, my_data FROM RankedData WHERE rank=1
)
```